# getFooter not working in accord with replaceText

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having problems with this common code to update dates when opening a document. It works just fine with getBody and getHeader but with getFooter - nada. No errors, nothing. Just cold water.

Is it me or is it a bug?

```
function onOpen() {
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "d.M.yyyy"); 
  var pattern = "\\b\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{4}\\b"; 
  var footer = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFooter();
  footer.editAsText().replaceText(pattern, date);
}
```

Comment: …And a bonus question: if i want to tweak the timestamp, is it +3 or +03:00 that I need to add?

Comment: Mmm-kay. If I create a new doc it works. So there's something wrong with the doc.

Comment: Is the structure / content of your footer different to the body / header? What is a sample content of your footer?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me perhaps it will work for you:

```
function onOpen() {
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "d.M.yyyy"); 
  var pattern = "\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{4}"; 
  var footer = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFooter();
  //DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(footer.getText()+ "/" + date), "Display");
  footer.editAsText().replaceText(pattern, date);
}
```

The only other possible issue is that onOpen() is a simple trigger so it can't do anything that requires a permission.